# How to create a list of content in a page that can be fan only voted (one unique vote per fan) and counted?

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

Maybe this is a really basic question but I have never done something with facebook before and I need to get this done in a matter of days, so I just need some guidelines and your help is crucial.

I'm running a contest and I need to have during a public vote phase a way of fans of my page vote on the submissions of the contesters. The vote must be unique and I need to have the number of votes in each item counted and display.

I think this is pretty straight forward but I don't even now how to start: should I develop a facebook application, or just a landing page with some code on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need an application that authenticates the user.  In other words the user will have to connect with your app. This will give you access to the FBID which you can then use to check to see if the user has already voted.  As for keeping track you'll probably need a database to store the votes in. Without authentication the most you'll be able to tell is if the user has liked the current page the app is installed on.